# How do I create an ABAB graph in base R?

Tags: r, plot, radix

I am trying to create a graph in base r to show results from a single-case design study. I need to be able to break the line for each section of the study. I know I can use SCVA but I want to draw the graph myself so I can have more control over it. When I add my lines() I cannot get them to align with the points. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I put some sample code below. I also included an image of the graph produced by the code.

```
x <- c(5, 7, 10, 20, 23, 25, 4, 8, 6, 21, 28, 25)
y <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "B2", "B2", "B2")

plot(x)
lines(x[y=="A1"])
lines(x[y=="B1"])
lines(x[y=="A2"])
lines(x[y=="B2"])
```

[Plot from the code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o35Tx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you need to specify the x.

```
plot(x, xaxt="n")
lines(1:3, x[y=="A1"])
lines(4:6, x[y=="B1"])
lines(7:9, x[y=="A2"])
lines(10:12, x[y=="B2"])
axis(side=1, at=c(2,5,8,11), labels=unique(y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I hope this helps.

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
x <- c(5, 7, 10, 20, 23, 25, 4, 8, 6, 21, 28, 25)
y <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "B2", "B2", "B2")
data <- data.frame(x,y,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,color=y))+geom_line()
```

[image]